# If-exists-UPDATE-else-INSERT with Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, exists

is there a way to write this same SQL atomic instruction using Entities and LinQ?

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @Id)
UPDATE MyTable SET name = @name
ELSE
INSERT INTO MyTable (@Id, @name)

or do you need to call a stored procedure from within the EF?

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework keeps track of the lifespan of objects:

- If the object was initialized from a query, the framework understands a record should exist in the database and will perform an `UPDATE` when pushing changes back to the database.
- If the object was initialized in code, the framework understands it as a "new" object and performs an `INSERT` when pushing the changes to the database.

If you wish to have a single piece of SQL called, regardless of whether an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation is required, you will have to specify a stored procedure.